# Can't access my class library in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, dll, webforms

**I have two projects in one solution :**

- Class Library for my BLL and DAL classes
- Web Application for my PL

---

Now I just use the keyword "using" in the BLL and DAL classes and get access to their methods easily. but now I try to reference the BLL and DAL in the web application project through the "using" keyword but it won't let me (the name space couldn't be found (are you missing reference ?)) .. then I tried to reference the library's dll (grabbed it from the ClassLibrary/bin/debug) and the same error just popped out again!

> Summery: My solution consists of two
>   projects (ClassLibrary and a
>   WebApplication) and I want to
>   use/reference the classes/dlls of the
>   class library in the web application

***Edit***
Guys! I already added the reference and it appears in the references folder, I've added both the project and the dll and still it won't compile! .. very weird isn't it!

***Edit2***
I tried creating a new solution and it worked like a charm, I tried to place the class library in like a subfolder in the solution folder or something and I thought as long as it referenced it will work okay! but it didn't.

The new solution I didn't change the locations at all and it worked after referencing the CLassLibrary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add a project reference.  In the Add Reference dialog look for a "Projects" tab.

Comment: I'm able to add the reference to the project and the dll .. then I build the project and still! the compiler won't see the class library!

Comment: Marked as answer .. your all provided the same answer but since you cared to type the words properly and was the first answer, so thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the references and click on add reference, then you can add dll as project reference or from bin folder of main web project.

Once you add the dll it should compile.

Comment: I added both the dll and the project .. and still! :S:S!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Web Application Project, correct? If it was a Website Project, you would add your code to the App_Code folder; namespaces are not used.

Open the References folder in VS Solution Explorer and check for broken reference icons. Try toggling between Release and Debug - compile and try again.

Comment: Actually I'm using Web Application

Comment: Then add a reference by right-clicking references folder and pointing to the project DLL in the bin folder for each of your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error. Everything is designed properly and set up correctly but it didn't work. I realized that copy & pasting class files from another location doesn't work as expected. I needed to right click and "add new" classes, then paste my code into them.

As soon as I began using the "Add New" method, this was fixed. This may be a setting I have in VS2008, but I couldn't locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it, the answer is actually simple.

I discovered it when I created a class library and noticed it made a `Class1.cs`.
From there i was able to "using 'MyLibrary'", however as soon as i deleted it, it said unable to find the namespace 'xyz'.

Im not very good at navigating and referencing in VS, but it has something to do with the namespaces.. If you dont know how to reference correctly(like me), just change all your imported classes Namespaces to the main project namespace, then slap all the classes directly into the main project.

Worked for me.